# react-native set ENVFILE file for builds / archives

Tags: xcode, react-native, android-studio, devops, environment

I'm really confused about production / development builds in react-native.  I can get my app working on both iOS and Android by using the package scripts in the terminal

```
ENVFILE='/path/to/.env' react-native run-ios
ENVFILE='/path/to/.env' react-native run-android
```

Thats great for running my app locally, but how do I run this command when creating archives through xcode?

I successfully installed react-native-config and I have the variables I need in the JS and native files, its just the final step of using this is prod or staging builds for devices.

I've managed to create fastlane scripts that build and deploy my app (and I can reference my .env vars in fastlane scripts) but that still doesn't bundle my app with the .env vars inside.  Its probably something obvious but i'm not understanding the concept at all.

Ive been referencing this tutorial [here](https://dev.to/calintamas/how-to-manage-staging-and-production-environments-in-a-react-native-app-4naa), and noticing the part about adding a pre-script to each Scheme in xcode:

```
".env" > /tmp/envfile
```

But I dont know what the current working directory on that script is, and Im using yarn workspaces so my node_modules folder is not at the root of the RN project (doesnt that even matter?). I've tried multiple paths to my .env from here but nothing works, but I also dont know how to test this script.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? I am having trouble trying to pass the ENVFILE arg in through XCode.

Answer (score 0):

I've successfully gotten it to work using Fastlane. I followed this guide for the Fastlane setup:

https://github.com/thecodingmachine/react-native-boilerplate/blob/master/documentation/docs/3_Guides/BetaBuild.md

After following the guide, I moved the Fastlane directory to the root of the project (and updated all paths).

And after that added the ENV variable when running the command, for example: `ENVFILE=.env.beta fastlane ios`, which is easy to add as a script in package.json.

It's also possible to use the dotenv feature in Fastlane, see https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/issues/13494#issuecomment-428941643.

Bottom line is that Fastlane will use the environment variable when running the packager, meaning that react-native-config will successfully pick it up and use the proper env-file.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I've used that article a lot actually to get to where I am today.  But it doesn't really tell you the steps to run from command line.  The end goal is to get to a point when I don't need to open xcode or android studio

Comment: Ah, then we're in the same position. I haven't done it yet but it should be possible using Fastlane. Have you done those parts of that guide too?

Comment: Yes I have fastlane set up and it’s amazing for uploading straight to the App Store connect in beta from just 1 command. But I don’t know how to test a beta build or production build locally from the command line. - I have since upgraded to RN 61 so it might be easier but havnt got to that point yet

Comment: @conor909 I've updated my answer with my current (and working) solution.